# reduce line width of seaborn pointplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, pointplot

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks")
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
g = sns.factorplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise)
```

In the plot above, if I specify scale as 0.5, it reduces line width but not width of confidence interval lines. Is there a way to reduce width of confidence interval lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may get linewidth of first line and set it for all other lines of factor plot:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
sns.set(style="ticks")
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
g = sns.factorplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise, scale=.5)
lw = g.ax.lines[0].get_linewidth() # lw of first line
plt.setp(g.ax.lines,linewidth=lw)  # set lw for all lines of g axes

plt.show()
```

[image]

And you can set line width for every line in a cycle:

```
for l in g.ax.lines:
    print(l.get_linewidth())
    plt.setp(l,linewidth=5)
```

Output:

```
1.575
3.15
3.15
3.15
1.575
3.15
3.15
3.15
1.575
3.15
3.15
3.15
```

Bold lines are according to confidential intervals.

After set line width to 5 all lines became the same:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

If you want to change the width of all lines (except axes) in the plot, you can simply change the parameter `"lines.linewidth"` in the matplotlib `rcparam` through seaborns `set` function. Simply add `rc={"lines.linewidth":0.7}` as a parameter in your call of `sns.set`. Likewise you can also change all (or at least most) of the default design options.

Example:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks", rc={"lines.linewidth": 0.7})
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
g = sns.factorplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise)
```

This results in the following plot:

[image]

The original plot (without `rc={"lines.linewidth":0.7}`) was:

[image]